# Given three integers a, b, and n,output the following series: a+20b,a+20b+21b,......,a+20b+21b+...+2n−1ba+20b,a+20b+21b,......,a+20b+21b+...+2n−1b

Tags: java, loops

> Constraints:
>
> - 0≤t≤500
> - 0≤a,b≤50
> - 1≤n≤15
>
> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 2
> 0 2 10
> 5 3 5
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> 2 6 14 30 62 126 254 510 1022 2046
> 8 14 26 50 98
> ```

This works in my IDE but when I try it in an online editor in hackerrank.com it throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line foundat
>   java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)at
>   Solution.main(Solution.java:24)

Please explain why this happens.Thanks!

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[10];
        int[] b = new int[10];
        int[] n = new int[10];
        int t;
        int sum;
        StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();

        Scanner iput = new Scanner(System.in);

        t = Integer.parseInt(iput.nextLine());

        if (t <= 500) {

            for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
                a[i] = Integer.parseInt(iput.next());
                b[i] = Integer.parseInt(iput.next());
                n[i] = Integer.parseInt(iput.next());
                iput.nextLine();
            }
        } else
            System.out.println("Enter value less than 500");

        if (t <= 500) {

            for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {

                if (a[i] <= 50 && b[i] <= 50 && n[i] <= 15 && n[i] != 0) {

                    for (int j=0;j<n[i];j++) {

                        sum = a[i];

                        for (int k = j;k >=0; k--) {

                            sum+=Math.pow(2,k)*b[i];
                        }
                        sb=sb.append(Integer.toString(sum)).append(" ");
                    }
                    System.out.println(sb);
                    sb.delete(0,sb.toString().length());
                } else
                    System.out.println("Enter the values within the allowed limits");
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: It is an online exercise (like a challenge!).Please suggest a way to complete it.

Comment: Why do you use `Integer.parseInt(iput.next())` instead of `iput.nextInt()`?

Comment: when i use nextInt() i couldn't give input in the format specified in the question.

Comment: Also it doesn't work for custom input too!!

Comment: @NawinSS It should be *your* fault that *you* coundn't give input. https://ideone.com/8M3joq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `iput.nextLine();` on line 24 so that no extra reading will happen.

Comment: Thanks it works after I removed that line!!!But can u explain the happenings behind the scene?

Comment: Is there a way to answer this challenge better!?.Becoz apparently this doesn't work for all the test cases!!Any help is much appreciated.Thanks..

Comment: @NawinSS did you manage to answer this? i am facing same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I think the below should work. Because value of T can be up to 500 So the array can be either int[] a = new int[t] or new int[500].

Note if you are using int[t] the get the value of t before defining a,b and n.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[500];
        int[] b = new int[500];
        int[] n = new int[500];
        int t;
        int sum;
        StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();

        Scanner iput = new Scanner(System.in);

        t = Integer.parseInt(iput.nextLine());

        if (t <= 500) {

            for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
                a[i] = Integer.parseInt(iput.next());
                b[i] = Integer.parseInt(iput.next());
                n[i] = Integer.parseInt(iput.next());
            }
        } else
            System.out.println("Enter value less than 500");

        if (t <= 500) {

            for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {

                if (a[i] <= 50 && b[i] <= 50 && n[i] <= 15 && n[i] != 0) {

                    for (int j=0;j<n[i];j++) {

                        sum = a[i];

                        for (int k = j;k >=0; k--) {

                            sum+=Math.pow(2,k)*b[i];
                        }
                        sb=sb.append(Integer.toString(sum)).append(" ");
                    }
                    System.out.println(sb);
                    sb.delete(0,sb.toString().length());
                } else
                    System.out.println("Enter the values within the allowed limits");
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hackerrank_loop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int j = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            int b = sc.nextInt();
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int x = 1;
            int o = a;
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                o = o + x * b;
                System.out.print(o);
                x = x << 1;
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved in this way the problem.
For sure it can be done better.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int q=in.nextInt();
    int[][] app;

    if(q<0 && q>500){
        System.out.println("ERROR = Select a valid value o q");
    }else{
        app= new int[q][3];
        for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
            app[i][0] = in.nextInt();
            app[i][1] = in.nextInt();
            app[i][2]= in.nextInt();
        }
        for (int one=0;one<q;one++){
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            int a = app[one][0];
            int b = app[one][1];
            int n = app[one][2];

            int sum = a;
            for (int two=0; two < n; two++){
                sum = sum + b*(int)Math.pow(2D,new Double(two));
                sb.append(sum);
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(sb);
        }

    }




    in.close();
```